# How to reference a web project from another web project with Ivy and Resolve in workspace

Tags: eclipse, ivy, ivyde

I have 2 web project: myLibraryProject and myWebProject

myWebProject depends on myLibraryProject, and each use ivy for dependency management:

myLibraryProject ivy.xml:

```
<ivy-module>
    <info organisation="it.me" module="my-library" />
    <!-- ... configurations and dependencies ... -->
</ivy-module>
```

myWebProject ivy.xml:

```
<ivy-module>
    <info organisation="it.me" module="my-web" />
    <!-- ... configurations... -->
    <dependencies>
         <dependency org="it.me" name="my-library" rev="latest.integration" />
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

I'm also using Resolve in workspace (within Eclipse and IvyDE plugin).

it's able to resolve the dependency, but it put `my-library.war` in `my-web.war/WEB-INF/lib/`

This way myWebProject can't use the library because it expect a jar, and not a war.

How can I tell... Eclipse? Ivy?... to not create a war but a jar?

Comment: It's hard to understand what your problem is but I suspect it has something to do with how you're calling the ivy "retrieve" task in the myWebProject build.xml file. Secondly are you publishing a jar from the myLibraryProject build.xml? I don't see an "publications" section in the ivy file.

Comment: i don't use ant (not now at least). I have the two projects in the eclipse workspace and tell ivy to "resolve in workspace". There is no publications, and if i tell <artifact name="my-library" type="jar" />, ivyDe (not ivy, the eclipse plugin) seem to ignore it.
I have also tried removing the ivy dependency and add the project directly from eclipse changing the extension to jar in Deployment Assembly, but this way it simply deploy WEB-INF/lib/my-library.jar, but internally is still a war, and does not work.

Comment: Ivy is primarily an ANT plugin. Sounds like an issue specific to the Eclipse plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't found a solution, but have at least found an explanation, and a work-around.

**The explanation**

As the ant [documentation](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/ivyde/history/latest-milestone/cpc/workspace.html) says:

> Note that WTP doesn't support IvyDE's workspace resolver. See the details in the page dedicated to [WTP integration](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/ivyde/history/latest-milestone/cpc/wtp.html#resolve-in-workspace).

**The work-around**

I've created a normal java project and a symbolic link ([can be done also on window](http://www.windows7home.net/how-to-create-symbolic-link-in-windows-7/)) to the web-project source folder in the normal project. This way IvyDE can *resolve in workspace* the normal project and all modifications still "propagate" in the web project.